# Storage of uninitialized global static variable in C programming

Tags: c, variables, memory, static, global

As I learn, uninitialized global static variable take memory space in bss. But while i am declaring a global static variable in my c program, the size of the bss is not increasing.

I tried:

```
#include<stdio.h>

static int i;

int main ()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you measure it?

Comment: What compiler and flags do you use? Variable is not used, it may be removed due to optimization. Generate map file and check it.

Comment: Add `printf("%d\n", i);` to justify including `<stdio.h>` and to use the variable.  Even then, the optimizer might beat us by replacing the `printf()` call with `puts("0");`.  You could add a loop to print `i` a number of times.

Comment: I measured it by size example(program name).exe command in command prompt.

Comment: I am using gcc compiler.

Comment: After adding printf("%d\n", i); size of data increased but size of bss is same.

Comment: Are you using the `-O` flag when you compile with gcc? In other words, do you have the optimizer active?

Comment: [This wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bss) might be useful to read.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose it's something like this:

In case of absense "static int i" in the above example, you have default align in size of int for .bss section, let's say 8 for 64b arch. I.e. there's bss_size=8.
When you add "static int i", you got the same bss_size=8, in this case for this static int.
If you add "static int i[2]", there will be shown bss_size=16
With "static int i[3]": bss_size=24, and so on.

For example on x86_64 linux:

```
$ cat a0.c
//static int i;
int main () { return 0; }

$ cat a1.c
static int i;
int main () { return 0; }

$ cat a3.c                                                                                                 
static int i[3];
int main () { return 0; }

$ gcc -o a0 a0.c; gcc -o a1 a1.c; gcc -o a3 a3.c
$ size a0 a1 a3
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   1228     544       8    1780     6f4 a0
   1228     544       8    1780     6f4 a1
   1228     544      24    1796     704 a3
```

if I am not mistaken, that default padding is here in ld's comment:

```
  .bss            :
  {
   *(.dynbss)
   *(.bss .bss.* .gnu.linkonce.b.*)
   *(COMMON)
   /* Align here to ensure that the .bss section occupies space up to
      _end.  Align after .bss to ensure correct alignment even if the
      .bss section disappears because there are no input sections.
      FIXME: Why do we need it? When there is no .bss section, we do not
      pad the .data section.  */
   . = ALIGN(. != 0 ? 64 / 8 : 1);
  }
```

Comment: After adding static int i as global variable, there is no change in the size of bss. The size of bss is same.

Comment: > After adding static int i as global variable, there is no change in the size of bss.

That's the way it is.
Try to increase size a bit more than minsize, for example 'static int i[10];',
and then check out bss_size (for example with 'size' program, like in the above reply).

Comment: int main() {return 0;}

static int i;
int main() { return 0;}
 static int i[3];
int main(){  return 0;}

static int i[10];
int main() {return 0;}
size work6.exe
   text    data     bss     dec     
   9708    2200    2432   14340    
size work7.exe
   9708    2200    2432   14340    
size work8.exe
   9708    2200    2432   14340    
size work9.exe
   9708    2200    2496   14404

Comment: @Acoinhastwosides from the shown output if i spot it correctly, bss is increased on 64 bytes from 2432 to 2496